# Is It possible to generate .pkpass extension file on an android device?

Tags: android, ios, iphone

How do I create a .pkpass extension file on an android device? This is possible on an iPhone device as it has an API to create it but there isn't such an API on Android.   Please help me, I don't know if it's possible or not.

Comment: you dont require any API to generate file for a particular extention, just profile file name with extention in syntax and it will get create  :)

Comment: http://www.ipass.pk/create.html#.UoNuL0MvmMF this is link to generate on website to create .pkpass extension file. i want to do same work in android mobile

Answer (score 1):

try this way,

```
// Code
File externalDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
File file = new File(externalDir.getAbsolutePath(), "abc.pkpass");

// Declare following permissions in Manifest.xml
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: so sir i can make .pkpass extention file using above code but sir i want same file which will genrate using http://www.ipass.pk/create.html#.UoNut0MvmMG this link, it possible. please check this site and guide me

Comment: sir but standard .pkpass extion file contain which files, i show u the link, https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Reference/PassKit_Bundle/Chapters/PackageStructure.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012026-CH1-SW1 in this link mentioned that it has .png .json file, is it right??

Comment: OK, then I have no idea regarding it.

Comment: Any one can guide me for this